# get a list of attribute values in xml

Tags: c#, xml, list, linq-to-xml

Is there a way to get a list of the values of the attributes for specific b (for example r4)?
`List<string>` that contains: "p3e3" and "p3e4"

```
<a>
  <b id="r4" Name="b 4">
    <P>
      <Pr id="p3e3" />
      <Pr id="p3e4" />
    </P>
  </b>
  <b id="r5" Name="b 5">
     ....
  </b>
</a>
```

The most I got was a `List<XElement>` that contained "`<Pr id="p3e3" />`" and "`<Pr id="p3e4" />`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var result = xdoc.Root.Elements("b")
                 .Where(b => (string)b.Attribute("id") == "r4")
                 .SelectMany(b => b.Element("P").Elements("Pr"))
                 .Select(pr => (string)pr.Attribute("id"));
```

Or with XPath:

```
var result = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("a/b[@id='r4']/P/Pr")
                 .Select(pr => (string)pr.Attribute("id"));
```

Comment: Hi! thanks! I got the same results, but I need only the Pr IDs, meaning p3e3 and p3e4 as strings. Because the next step will be to check if an ID that I get from another place is inside my list of IDs

Comment: @user990635 then project elements to ids: `Select(pr => (string)pr.Attribute("id"))`. I updated answer